# APPBAR space allocation issue in Windows XP

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-xp, appbar

I create an APPBAR in my WPF application, it is working fine in windows 7, but in XP it has an issue. After i close the application, i expect the space used by APPBAR should be free and reallocated to the desktop, but this does not happens in windows XP. But if i Lock/Unlock the taskbar then it allocate the space back to the system.

Kindly guide me towards some solution to it.

Comment: Don't know exactly, but did you try to close it programmatically before closing the program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  public static void RemoveAppBar(Window appbarWindow)
        {
            RegisterInfo info = GetRegisterInfo(appbarWindow);

            if (info.IsRegistered)
            {
                APPBARDATA abd = new APPBARDATA();
                abd.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(abd);
                abd.hWnd = new WindowInteropHelper(appbarWindow).Handle;
                SHAppBarMessage((int)ABMsg.ABM_REMOVE, ref abd);
            }
        }
```

Call this method on App.Exit event and pass your appbar window on it.